# Colored bars have appeard in my Visual Studio 2012 beside the line numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Today when I started Visual Studio 2012 at work I found some new colored bars.

We work on a shared remote server through RDP, so I asked around if someone has installed or updated anything. It seems no one has done "anything".

There are the bars I'm seeing:

[image: A screenshot of the bars.]

The leftmost bars, the green and yellow one, I know about. They show where the file has been edited since its opening (yellow means the changes has not been saved yet, green means they have been saved).

The rightmost one, I'm lost about them. They seem to *usually* mirror the leftmost, but not always. They persist through file close-reopen.

Through some tinkering, it seems the green rectangles means new lines added, the blue rectangles means existing lines modified and the red triangles means removed lines.

These are the information form Visual Studio's About window:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Installed Version: Premium

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012

Office Developer Tools   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Office Developer Tools

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual F# 2012   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Visual F# 2012

Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools   04941-004-0044006-02568
Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools

Git Source Control Provider   1.0.0.0


JetBrains ReSharper 7.0.1   C# Edition build 7.0.1098.2760 on 2012-08-27T14:31:12
JetBrains ReSharper 7.0.1 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2013 JetBrains, Inc.

JetBrains TeamCity Addin 7.1   build 7.1.667.137 on 2013-02-05T12:20:56 [Not Loaded]
JetBrains TeamCity Addin 7.1 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about TeamCity, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/. Copyright © 2000–2013 JetBrains, Inc.

NuGet Package Manager   2.2.40116.9051
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

StyleCop   4.7.41.0
Provides source code style and consistency tools. See http://www.stylecop.codeplex.com/ for more details.

Web Developer Tools   1.2.40308.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Page Inspector: Tool that offers an efficient way to decompose Web Applications and diagnose front-end issues.
Web Publishing: Extensions required for Web Publishing for both hosted servers as well as on premises.
Web Form Templates: Includes the default templates for Web Form Applications.
Editor Extensions: Includes HTML, CSS, and JS editor extensions that greatly enhance the development experience.

Git source control provider
Demo.
```

I have these extensions installed:

[image: The list of installed extensions.]

Can someone shed some light on this, and how can I disable them? My OCD is complaining about the conflicting information...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They come from the [GIT source control provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/). I suppose your project is versioned, so those bars give you information about lines that are changed in some way, and what is the nature of the change.

Comment: You're right, if I disable the "Git source control provider" the bars disappear. The curious thing is I don't have that provider active in my settings - http://i.imgur.com/ciaDMrj.png - so I didn't even think of it. Damn zombies... :\

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit menu 
Advanced /
View White Space Ctrl+E,S